# php echo line causes 500 internal server error

Tags: php, echo, internal-server-error

```
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('M dS, Y', $checkin);

echo($dt1);
```

When I add the echo line I receive a 500 internal server error.

Comment: `$dt1` is a object use e.g `echo $dt1->format('d.m.Y');` see http://uk.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: and you have `display_errors` turned off so that no errors will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dt1` is an object ..So you cant simply echo it.It will raise error.You would need to do like..

```
echo $dt1->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: its the answer ..and i have just modified it..not as just copy paste .:p